# How to use find_by_username with case_sensitive: false?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How to use find_by_username with case_sensitive: false?

I explain my issue. I have this script to take the username tagged (after @) and to check if it is a "existing user" or not.

```
text.gsub! (/@(\S+)/) do |match|
  user = User.find_by_username($1)
    if
    else
    end
  end
```

In this way if the text is @Mike and the user signed is Mike, it is ok.
BUT if the text is @mike and the user signed is Mike, it doesn't work.

Hot to add a case_sensitive false in find_by_username?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: You can split `text` and create a regular expression to use a function of your database to filter the rows based on a that (LIKE, ILIKE, ...)  instead of using gsub and making one query for each match.

Comment: is not a good idea to use "User.where('LOWER(username) = ?', $1.downcase).first" ?

Comment: It's better to avoid doing repetitive queries to the database when you don't really need to do so, in your case it seems you can create a regular expression that can be used with LIKE. I can't go further because I don't know what values might `text` have.

Comment: text is the comment written by an user. I have to check if he added @ to tag someone and then to check if the "user tagged"  exists or not.